# NPM ERR! EBADPLATFORM

Tags: laravel, npm

Estoy actualizando npm y la consola me dice que estoy usando linux en un pc que tiene windows, no entiendo, no me había pasado antes!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esa terminal es de Linux. Tal vez `git bash`? O estás conectado via `ssh` a un terminal Linux?

Comment: Es PuttY, se conecta por SSH

Comment: No. Te está diciendo que intentó instalar el binding win64 de esbuild y no pudo justamente porque tu sistema es linux. Ahora, por qué está intentando instalar el paquete de windows, ni idea. Yo lo que haría en tu lugar es ir al repositorio de esbuild y ver si entre las issues alguien ha reportado algo que suene similar